# Select only regex match from a continuous string

Tags: python, regex

I want to use this regex

```
r"Summe\d+\W\d+"
```

to match this string

`150,90‡50,90‡8,13‡Summe50,90•50,90•8,13•Kreditkartenzahlung`

but I want to only filter out this specific part

`Summe50,90`

I can select the entire string with this regex but I'm not sure how to filter out only the matching part

here is the function it is in where i am trying to get the amount from a pdf:

```py
    def get_amount(url):
      data = requests.get(url)
      with open('/Users/derricdonehoo/code/derric-d/price-processor/exmpl.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data.content)

      pdfFileObj = open('exmpl.pdf', 'rb')
      pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

      pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
      text = pageObj.extractText().split()

      regex = re.compile(r"Summe\d+\W\d+")

      matches = list(filter(regex.search, text))
      for i in range(len(matches)):
        matchString = '\n'.join(matches)


      print(matchString)
```

as described above, I would like guidance on how I can best filter out a part of this string so that it returns just the matching portion. preferably with varying lengths of characters on either side but that's not a priority.

thanks!!

Comment: `\W` doesn't match commas

Comment: Why not `r"Summe\d+,\d+"`?

Comment: Your expected result should be `150,90‡50,90‡8,13‡50,90•8,13•Kreditkartenzahlung` then?

Comment: What does "filter out" mean in this context? Just write down the exact output you want. Also having a couple more examples of input-output would make things easier  since from one example one might think that something matters (or not) but it does not really (or it does actually). For example from your statement I'd say that just using `text.replace("Summe50,90", "")` should solve your problem since it certainly "filters out Summe50,90" in a sense and it works in the only "test case" you provided.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza filter out a part of this string so that it returns just the matching portion.. so the regex i gave matches exactly the portion i mentioned i want "filtered", and i want just that as output. the parts that is not "Summe50,90"  do not get returned. so at the end of the function it should just return "Summe50,90"

Comment: @Bakuriu I specified just now above but all i want is "Summe50,90" as output, and the rest of the string is the part i want to filter the rest from. so like the opposite of your suggestion almost, where instead of replacing "Summe50,90", we preserve only "Summe50,90" and get rid of the rest.

Comment: @Tomerikoo im not looking for a matching regex here, but a way to maybe use regex to select only a part of the string -> "Summe50,90" and have this part be the output

Comment: I don't seem to understand the problem. If the specific RegEx is not your problem, all you need to do is return its result and use it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3483203 ... it seems to work just fine in this scenario

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah but this regex returns the entire string, not just the matching part. 
`150,90‡50,90‡8,13‡Summe50,90•50,90•8,13•Kreditkartenzahlung` is the string this regex returns because it matches `"Summe50,90"` but i only want this function to return `"Summe50,90"` and not the entire string

Comment: I still don't understand. Simply right `match = re.search("Summe\d+,\d+", text)` and then to get your result `res = match.group()`

Comment: ok, i didnt know this group method but another guy has also mentioned it.. @Tomerikoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want, your regex is correct but you must get the match after searching for it.

```
  regex = re.compile(r"Summe\d+\W\d+")
  text = ["150,90‡50,90‡8,13‡Summe50,90•50,90•8,13•Kreditkartenzahlung"]

  matches = []
  for t in text:
    m = regex.search(t)
    if m:
      matches.append(m.group(0))

  print(matches)
```

[re.search](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.search) returns a [Match](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#match-objects) object on success, `None` on failure, and that object contains all the information about your matching regex. To get the whole match you call [Match.group()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.Match.group).

Comment: `re.findall(...` also.

Comment: thanks but i am getting error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: why is this downvoted? its the closest answer here  everything else is going on about the regex pattern

Comment: @derric-d they downvoted because I made some mistakes, should be right now. :)

Comment: @SilvanoCerza ah you are a life saver my friend! my brain has turned to mush today and you helped me very much! thanks for your time!

Comment: @Tomerikoo I've included the loop to keep the solution similar to the OP's example, it's obvious that looping a list with an element it's redundant. :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this simple expression might likely work here,

```
(Summe.+?)•
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(Summe.+?)•"

test_str = "150,90‡50,90‡8,13‡Summe50,90•50,90•8,13•Kreditkartenzahlung"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZcLEO/1/)

Comment: you are right that that matches it, but i want to filter the part of the string that matches and return only it. maybe i should edit my question so that is clear.. but thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is a convenient way to "grab" your match.

```py
import re

text = "150,90‡50,90‡8,13‡Summe50,90•50,90•8,13•Kreditkartenzahlung"
match = re.search("Summe\d+\W\d+", text)
if match:
    res = match.group()

>>> print(res)
'Summe50,90'
```

Note that `group` accepts an index to return a group from inside your regex but since this one doesn't use groups (Which are surrounded by `(...)` in your regex) you simply call it like that.

---

If you want to find all occurences of said pattern use `re.findall`:

```py
import re

text = "150,90‡50,90‡8,13‡Summe50,90•50,90•Summe8,13•Kreditkartenzahlung"
matchs = re.findall("Summe\d+\W\d+", text)

>>> print(matches)
['Summe50,90', 'Summe8,13']
```

In this case a list with all matches (already strings, not Match objects) will be returned. Again, if you use capture groups, a list of tuples will be returned where each tuple contains all the groups for a match.

Read about the methods - [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Answer (score 0):

`\W` will probably match everything up to Kredit...

```py
regex = r'Summe\d+,\d{2}'
```

should match the first 50,90 after Summe.

If the separating comma is too specific (because it might come as a dot) you can use a character set:

```py
regex = r'Summe\d[,.]\d{2}'
```

Comment: Nice idea but at the same time you are limiting the second number for just 2 digits. That also might be "too specific"...